# What does "the long-tail of coins" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean **coins with small quantities/ rare coins**?

“I think sentiment across Asia has shifted to a more speculative nature, and ETH has been driving interest in the altcoin market,” says Jonathan Leong, CEO of BTSE, a cryptocurrency trading platform based in the British Virgin Islands. “For sure Japanese traders love XRP, and Chinese traders like to trade exchange coins and DeFi coins, among others. Korean investors are risk takers and trade **the long-tail of coins**,” he says.

Source:https://www.forbes.com/sites/kenrapoza/2021/05/02/what-are-the-hottest-cryptocurrencies-in-china-korea--japan/

Answer (score 1):

It is a statistical metaphor.  In a bell-shaped distribution most individuals are near the average. A few are a long way from the average.  These are said to be in the "tails" of the distribution.

So "in the long-tail" means far from the average, uncommon, non-typical. Koreans (the article claims) like to trade in less well known (and therefore risker) forms of cryptocurrency.

It is not a common metaphor for people who are not economists.

Comment: You're quite right in terms of the "statistical distribution" reference, but I'm not sure ***exactly what this is supposed to mean*** in context. Koreans are somehow "atypical", but in terms of the bell-shaped distribution of ***what**?* Do they trade altcoins ***more often**?* For ***larger transaction values**?* Are Korean cryptocurrency traders more likely to "invest" using ***borrowed money**?* Unless we know the specific reason why they're "outliers", the reference effectively means nothing - it's just a jargon "buzz-word".